# How to flatten dependency graph?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new with Apache Spark,
can i get a snippet of how to implement 'flattening' for dependency graph? 
i.e lets say I have:
nodes :A,B,C
edges : (A,B),(B,C)

it would result with a new Graph:
nodes:A,B,C
edges:(A,B)(A,C)(B,C)

Comment: This is non-trivial. There's certainly no out-of-the-box way to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: didn't try anything yet, i have just tried to understand other algorithms like most short path so i can customize/modify it, the reason why i looked at that algorithm is because he is recursive too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Presuming each node is in its own row

```
A
B
C
```

2) Do a CROSS JOIN with self as first step.

```
A A
A B
A C
B A
B B
B C
C A
C B
C C
```

2) In second step filter out all the rows where Node name is repeated.

```
A B
A C
B A
B C
C A
C B
```

3) Post that derive another field from two fields that would tell you the edge.

```
A B   AB
A C   AC
B A   BA
B C   BC
C A   CA
C B   CB
```

You would need to convert this into the (Scala/Python) syntax though. Hope this helps.